# Avoid jquery conflict in my jsf application

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jsf, richfaces

I load jquery in my jsf project. I load header part only.

Before i load the jquery, link and menu actions are perfectly worked.  **(Not load jquery)**

But, after i load the jquery the link action and menu action are not worked.

i use  **jQuery.noConflict();**   and **$.noConflict();** But no more improvement.

Actually, why this problem occur when i load the jquery.

```
 <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">              
    <a4j:loadScript src="../../scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"/>          

     <script type="text/javascript">  
             jQuery.noConflict();                   
      </script>     

</head>
```

And also i use **jquery-1.4.2.min.js**. But not work my menu and link action.

I put more effort for this.
i hope, here i will get some solution.
Help me.
Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: try one thing try loading the same page in FF, check its error console and see what is the problem exactly

Comment: Avoid using `for(x in ...` on arrays - I think JQuery messes that up.

Comment: *"after i load the jquery the link action and menu action are not worked"* **HOW** do they not work? What happens? Do you have any errors in the console? Have you walked through with a debugger (Firebug, Chrome/Safari Dev Toosl, etc.) to figure out what's happening?

Comment: @sje397: No, jQuery doesn't add anything to `Array.prototype` (you're thiking of Prototype and MooTools). And even then, it's not that Prototype/MooTools mess things up, code using `for..in` on arrays and assuming it will only see indexes is *already* messed up. More: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html

Comment: @Eswar Thambi nee Mech eswar ah!! I am chendur da...

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: mca 2006-09 batch

Comment: Thanks for your support. I see the following error in IE error console. Line:266 Char107 Error:Object doesn't support property or method code:0 URL:http://192.168.0.182:9090/TestProject/faces/general/main.jsp.  But i load the jquery only in head part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
   <head>  
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">      

    <a4j:loadScript src="resource:///org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery/jquery.js" />                 
    <a4j:loadScript src="../scripts/highcharts.js"/>  

    <script type="text/javascript">  

     jQuery.noConflict();  

     jQuery(document).ready(function()  
     {  
          ....  
          ....  
     });  

 </script>  </head>
```