# RichFaces component rich:input does not seem to work with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

Continuing using JQuery with RichFaces components, I've noticed that when you import one of the JQuery scripts, particularly this one: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js", one of RichFaces components, "rich:inplaceInput", doesn't seem to work.  The input appears, but the javascript it uses disappears, so no matter how many times you click it, nothing happens.  Here is my header:

```
    <f:view>
       <html>
         <head>
              <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
              <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
              <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>            
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/custom-styles.css" />
              <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/customJS.js"></script>
              <a4j:loadScript src="resource:///jquery.js"/>
         </head>
       </html>
    </f:view>
```

And in the body I create a simple  and there I have a simple panel and a simple inplace input:

```
      <rich:panel id="simplePanel" style="width:560px;height:100px;">
          <rich:inplaceInput id="sample" defaultLabel="Some text" />
      </rich:panel>
```

That's all, and it works only when I remove the first script import, the one that includes "jquery.min" javascript file.

Any idea why this happens?  Is it a bug in RichFaces?  Is there a workaround or is it only possible after upgrading RichFaces? (I'm using 3.3.3 version)

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Richfaces , but it seems that it come with jquery out of the box

and can be used like this (reference to the version built-it jQuery)

```
<a4j:loadScript
src="resource:///org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery/jquery.js" />
```

When you try to import another `jQuery.js` file it results in conflicts...

Look here [Avoid jquery conflict in my jsf application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459174/avoid-jquery-conflict-in-my-jsf-application)

and Here [Richfaces with jQuery](https://community.jboss.org/thread/14877)

to learn more...