# How to pass 2 values in function call in jQuery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

Hi I have jQuery function and in that I have called servlet in that and also passes 2 values with it but it shows `NullPointerException`.
I don't know why but I think I am wrong in placing arguments in it.

My code :

```
function addProductById(pId,pMqty){
                $.getJSON("addtocart?pid=" + pId + "&minqty="+ pMqty +"&rand=" + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1), function(json) {
                    alert(json.msg);
                });
            }
```

here I am passing 2 variable pId and pMqty to servlet addtocart but it's not receiving in servlet.
Any idea why it's not going there ?

and I have also call this function to JavaScript on button click :

```
onclick='addProductById(" + this.id + ","+ this.minqty +");'
```

ANy help please ?

Java Script Code :

```
tableRow: function tableRow(product){

    this.id = product.pId;
    this.image = product.pImage;
    this.name = product.pName;
    this.price = product.pPrice;
    this.feature = product.pFeature;
    this.minqty = product.pMqty;

    var image = "<div class='mainitemlist'><div class='mainitemlistimage'><a href='product?pid=prdID'><img src='product_images/prdIMAGE' height='125px' width='100px' style='border-radius:2px;'></a></div>";
    var name = "<div class='mainitemlistname'><div align='center'><a href='product?pid=prdID' style='color: #9caeb9;text-decoration: none;'>prdNAME</a></div></div>";
    var price = "<div class='mainitemlistprice'><div align='center'>prdPRICE</div></div>";
    var features = "<div class='mainitemlistfeatures'><div align='center'> <!--prdFEATURE-->MOQ : prdMINQTY</div><div align='center'><button type='button' style='display: none;margin-top: 5px;' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='addProductById(" + this.id + ","+ this.minqty +");'>Add To Cart</button></div></div></div>";


    this.generateHTML = function generateHTML(){
        html = "";      
        html += image.replace("prdIMAGE", this.image).replace("prdID", this.id);
        html += name.replace("prdNAME", this.name).replace("prdID", this.id);
        html += price.replace("prdPRICE", this.price);
        html += features.replace("prdFEATURE", this.feature).replace("prdMINQTY", this.minqty);;
        return html;        
    };

}
```

To display data using Java Script, here `container` is div, I have just call this div in jsp page. :

```
display: function display(){        

    var node = document.getElementById('container');

    while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }

    var html = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < catalogue.product.length; i++){              
        var tableRow = new catalogue.tableRow(catalogue.product[i]);  
        html += tableRow.generateHTML();    
    }

    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: print the url: `addtocart?pid=" + pId + "&minqty="+ pMqty +"&rand=" + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)` to the console and check if it is a well formed URL and also check if the url works from the browser

Comment: @codeMan - Sir problem is value of pMqty is not passing in function. Problem is in `onclick='addProductById(" + this.id + ","+ this.minqty +");'`, it works completely only with `pId` but after adding `minqty` is got problem, I think it's syntax error in passing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:-

```
onclick='addProductById("' + this.id + '","' + this.minqty +'");'
```

The single quotes in the `onclick` attribute are not closed properly, that is why those values are not going.

And test it like:-

```
function addProductById(pId, pMqty) {

    // You can test the values here
    alert(pId + ', ' + pMqty);

    // your code here..
}
```

Comment: @palash  -I have tried `alert(pId + ', ' + pMqty);` but in pMqty it shows undefined. I think problem is in `onclick='addProductById(" + this.id + ","+ this.minqty +");'` when I am using only `this.pId` it works but it's not working with quantity data.

Comment: could you please post the html markup where you are using the `minqty` attribute!?!?

Comment: I don't have use it in html, I have used it in JavaScript. I am posting part of my Java Script.

Comment: Ok, please check inside the `tableRow` function the value for `alert( this.minqty+', ' + product.pMqty)` and put it after this line `this.minqty = product.pMqty;` of code...

Comment: alert is not working in javascript tablerow function. I have do as per your suggestion but it's not working. In `var features = "<div class='mainitemlistfeatures'><div align='center'> <!--prdFEATURE-->MOQ : prdMINQTY</div><div align='center'><button type='button' style='display: none;margin-top: 5px;' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='addProductById(" + this.id + ","+ this.minqty +");'>Add To Cart</button></div></div></div>";` this line `prdMINQTY` shows the value for quantity. I just need this value which shows undefined.

Comment: Yo Yo Yo I have done it yaar.. It's take a time but at the end got the result of my mehnat... Thanx for the guidance..

Comment: I have made some other changes and addition into code and now it works smoothly for me. Hey I have other problem of jQuery confliction. I have used 2 jQuery one for image slider and other for showing cart so showing cart doesn't work. on other page it works bcz image slider is not on that page. Any idea how to avoid confliction ?

Comment: Have a look at the [jQuery.noConflict() API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)...

Comment: @palasH - I have used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459174/avoid-jquery-conflict-in-my-jsf-application and work smoothly.

Comment: Is it possible to call 1 JavaScript function and 1 jQuery function on button click. I have to use it in `onClick`.

Comment: It's better to use one `click` event only for an element. Either use js `onClick` or jQuery `.click( handler )`...

Comment: but sir I have put something different in that code bcz if user doesn't enter anything into `textbox` then it take `min order qty` as argument and if user enter any amount in `textbox` then that should be passed as an argument in `addProductById(pId,pMinqty)` function.

Comment: Yes Sir, and I am confused that how to do that ? Any idea ? Now I am going If you ll get solution then please post to me..

Comment: I am looking into it, but in the mean time could you post it as a separate question. You might get some good ideas or suggestion on it from other users too..

Comment: Thank you sir. By the way I am from Gujarat, If any Java Fresher or 6 months experienced vacancy then please inform me sir.